# MySQL foreign key or not?

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

I have the following three MySQL tables and I'm wondering whether a field is a foreign key or not.

When a user completes a test from the *tests* table, a row gets inserted in the *scores* table whereby the *test_id* equals a *test_id* from the *tests* table.

However, a user may complete a computer auto-generated test that is NOT from the *tests* table, and when this happens, the *test_id* equals *'0'* which does not appear in the *tests* table.

That means *test_id* is not a foreign key in the *scores* table, correct?

```
scores:
score_id(PK, AI), test_id(FK?), module_id(FK)...

tests:
test_id(PK, AI), module_id(FK), user_id(PK), name...

modules:
module_id(PK, AI), name....
```

Comment: *it may also equal '0' which does appear in the tests table* so there is always a relation

Comment: @juergend Sorry, typo. It does not.

Comment: Use `NULL` instead of `0` and declare it to be a foreign key.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, given your reputation, I'm sure you have a good reason not to write that comment as an answer. To me, your solution seems like the right path to follow here, so I think it would be beneficial to the audience if you to give it more relevance by adding it as an answer.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I've added more info in the OP.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, you should have the column be a foreign key to the `tests` table.  You then have several options:

1. You can put a fake row in the `tests` table for those inferior "computer-generated" tests.  This could have a value of `0` and you pretty much have the same data structure you have now.
2. You can have a `TestType` column that distinguishes between different tests.  It might take the values `'Real'` and `'Computer-Generated'` for instances.  Then you would have a foreign key relationship to the `tests` table.  It would be `NULL` when the test type isn't the right type.
3. You can take a short-cut on (2) and just consider `NULL` values to be computer generated.

I don't know enough about your application, but I would go for (1) or (2), personally.

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: Personally I would go for number 1 and create the foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the relationship between scores and tests.

If some of the scores have a test_id of '0', this is most likely because they do not have a foreign key to the tests table. This is not a requirement unless specified.

This could be possible because a single score may not have a relationship to any test listed in the tests table.

Some databases will list these values as `NULL` whereas others will list as '0'

EDIT:

In addition (given your additional comments), this would NOT be a foreign key. See the below comment from Wikipedia

> Most database management systems provide mechanisms to ensure that
>   every non-null foreign key corresponds to a row of the referenced
>   table

Therefore, in a Relational Database, this would not be a foreign key if it has enforced  referential integrity constraints

Comment: I've added more info in the OP. That is correct, a score with a test_id of '0' does not refer to any of the tests in the tests table but is a computer-generated test.